# Is it safe to manually perform 'apt-get update' 's operation?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, package-management, upgrade, apt-offline

I am trying to **keep one my Ubuntu systems up-to-date**. The intended target is **Not Connected to the internet**. Am trying to get all the needed info from another machine with internet access.

After a bit of study, I found a way to achieve this. Can you please tell me if this is correct & safe?

> Here is my understanding of the apt-get process..
>
> 1. First, we run the command ***'apt-get update'*** : This connects to all the repositories mentioned in the *'/etc/apt/sources.list'*.. And,
>      **downloads all the Packages.gz** files like
>      (**in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz**)
>      & **saves them in a similar name** under *'/var/lib/apt/lists'* (for the
>      above mentioned url the corresponding file is
>      **in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_binary-amd64_Packages**)
> 2. Then, when we run ***'apt-get upgrade'*** (or) ***'apt-get install pkg_name'***, this **checks the locally installed package list with the local meta-data**
>      downloaded & stored at *'/var/lib/apt/lists'*. And, then gets the
>      download url from that & asks for user confirmation **before downloading
>      & installing the required packages**.

This is my plan to keep the isolated machine up-to-date..

1. **Get the list of packages to download** from the *'/etc/apt/sources.list'* conf file at the target machine..
2. **Download the meta-data** files Packages.gz **at another machine**..
3. **Copy** these files **to target machine's *'/var/lib/apt/lists'*** under appropriate filename.
4. **Run** the ***'apt-get --print-uris upgrade'*** (or) *'apt-get --print-uris --yes install pkg_name'* to get the list of all the packages needed for that machine.
5. **Download these packages** again **at the second machine**.
6. **Copy them to the target machine**.
7. **Run the *'dpkg -i pkg_list'*** to install all the missing packages.

I am able to achieve my goal using this process.

My question is : **Is this correct & reliable? Or is there an easier way to achieve this?**

Rangaraj

Comment: You have [already posted this question on other SE site](http://askubuntu.com/questions/667611/is-it-safe-to-manually-perform-apt-get-update-s-operation). Stack Exchange explicitly discourages posting on multiple sites. Moreover, your question is indeed more fit to Ask Ubuntu then Linux&Unix. I would recommend you being patient and asking on one site at once.

Comment: @MatthewRock - That said, the question has got better answers here than on AskUbuntu

Comment: @CharlesStewart I might also be mistaken that question belongs more to Ubuntu, since apt is used on several distributions; it probably is better fit here. However, asking on few Stack Exchange sites and seeing which one provides best answer is bad practice, and against the rules.

Answer (score 10):

This sounds like it may work, but personally, I'd just use [apt-offline](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/apt-offline.8.html).

From the manpage:

apt-offline  brings  offline package management functionality to Debian
       based system.  It can be used to download packages and its dependencies
       to  be  installed  later  on  (or  required  to  update) a disconnected
       machine.   Packages  can  be  downloaded  from  a  different  connected
       machine.

Excerpt from [Debian Administration](https://www.debian-administration.org/article/648/Offline_Package_Management_for_APT):

Using `apt-offline`:

- You generate a signature on your Debian box at home and carry the signature file on a removable medium
- Now you take the USB Stick (with the `apt-offline.txt` signature file) to the office machine which could be running any linux version or even Windows.
- There, you could run `apt-offline` giving it the signature file.
- `apt-offline` would generate you an archive file or a folder with all the data. That data can be copied on a removable media. The removable media can be attached back to the disconnected Debian box at home and installed. (e.g. "`apt-offline install /tmp/apt-offline.zip`")

Comment: Thank you, will have a look at `apt-offline`. But, it does require one Ubuntu machine to be connected to the internet, right?
I need my downloads to be on a Windows machine. Any idea how to run `apt-offline` on a windows machine?

Comment: @RangarajKS see http://superuser.com/questions/771044/how-to-make-apt-offline-on-windows for instructions on building `apt-offline` for Windows (but download the source from https://alioth.debian.org/frs/?group_id=100399 instead of the link given on superuser.com).

Comment: Thanks, @StephenKitt.. Really useful. Will give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

I used to have a "no internet" update process on my machine. This is how I did it:

First I used `apt-get --print-uris update > meta.list` to create a list of all files needed for updating the system. Using `wget`, I could run `wget -x -i meta.list` on any other machine to download the meta data on a USB stick. Back to my machine, I used the USB stick (`wget -x` creates a directory structure) to allow my system to update its meta data (The USB stick was configured as a local software repository). To install a package I generated the list of files I needed to download (`apt-get --print-uris upgrade > package.list`), used `wget` again on another machine to download all packages to my USB stick, and put the stick into my machine where I then could install from the local repository. I don’t remember the exact details, but this is basically it.

You can also use helper tools (e.g. [reprepro](https://wiki.debian.org/SettingUpSignedAptRepositoryWithReprepro) or [AptMedium](https://wiki.debian.org/AptMedium)) to ease the process. Personally, I did not have any problems with this method and it was very reliable.

Comment: did you run the `apt-get --print-uris` without running `apt-get update` first?

Comment: No, I started with ```apt-get --print-uris update > meta.list``` which prints the URIs needed for updating into a file.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted your first command as `upgrade` instead of `update`.. Yeah, I'm kinda trying to do the same thing you used to..  :-)

Comment: Don't you need to change name of meta files downloaded from `meta.list`, to the special format?! you didn't mentioned how you move meta data back to target machine, so `apt-get` can generate list of packages.

Comment: You are right; my answer was a bit unclear. I edited it in hope that it is easier to understand now.